# How to debug an error like "‘featureDefinitions’ is not a slot in class “list” while plotting in R?

Tags: r, runtime-error

I'm new to R and I'm continuously getting this error when I'm trying to plot the demo data-set that is given for xcms on bioconductor page.

http://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/vignettes/xcms/inst/doc/xcms.R

```
>raw_data <- readMSData(files = cdfs, pdata = new("NAnnotatedDataFrame", pd),
                   mode = "onDisk")
>raw_data <- filterRt(raw_data, c(2500, 4000))

>chr_raw <- chromatogram(raw_data, mz = mzr, rt = rtr)

>xchr <- findChromPeaks(chr_raw, param = CentWaveParam(snthresh = 2))

>sample_colors <- group_colors[xchr$sample_group]

>plot(xchr, col = sample_colors,
 peakBg = sample_colors[chromPeaks(xchr)[, "column"]])
```

**HERE I'M GETTING THESE ERROR:
Error in (function (cl, name, valueClass)  :
‘.processHistory’ is not a slot in class “list”**

**AND WHILE EXECUTING THIS :

```
>chr_1 <- chromatogram(filterFile(xdata, 1), mz = mzr_1)

>res <- refineChromPeaks(chr_1, MergeNeighboringPeaksParam(minProp = 0.05))
```

I'M GETTING THESE ERROR:

**Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  :
unable to find an inherited method for function ‘refineChromPeaks’ for signature ‘"XChromatograms", "MergeNeighboringPeaksParam"’****

**AND WHILE EXECUTING THIS :

```
>chr_adj <- chromatogram(xdata, rt = rtr, mz = mzr)

>plot(chr_adj, col = group_colors[chr_raw$sample_group], peakType = "none")
```

I'M GETTING THESE ERROR:

**Error in (function (cl, name, valueClass)  :
‘featureDefinitions’ is not a slot in class “list”****

I'm trying to debug them by re-installing all packages installed but I'm not able to understand the reason for this error.

CAN ANYONE PLEASE TELL ME WHAT IS THE SOLUTION FOR RECTIFYING THESE ERRORS?

Answer (score 0):

someone else was reporting in https://github.com/sneumann/xcms/issues/498
that it "Went away after upgrading to R 4.0.2". Yours, Steffen